# how to process a batch data when batch_size=None in Keras

Tags: keras

suppose I have data with shape (None, 32, 24) in Keras, means batch_size=None, I have a shared weight W with shape (24, 12), for each example X with shape (32, 24) in a batch , I want do matrix multiply Y = X @ W, shape of Y is (32, 12), the shape of final output is (None, 32, 12).
how can I get the final output in Keras?

I try to get the batch_size with inputs.get_shape()[0] and use it in range() function to do the matrix multiply, use K.stack to get the final output, but batch_size is NoneType, range() doesn't support it.

Comment: `K.dot()` can achieve it.

Comment: I know how to do matrix multiply